# How to get previous "x" number latest tag name?

Tags: git, github

Hi Iam currently using git describe --abbrev=0 to get the latest tag, but it only returns one, what argument do I pass, and how do get the last 20 latest tags?

I tried
user6346643
answer but it would also like it to not return duplicates

```
git describe --abbrev=0 $(git rev-list --tags --max-count=20)
```

[image]

Comment: What do the docs say?

Comment: @user6346643 answer is heading in the right direction but i would like not to get duplicates if possible

Comment: How do you know whether these are the *latest* tags? What if, say, `case-management_v3.2.0.90` is a really old tag, but bubbles to the top in whatever command sequence you use? What *is* a "latest" tag anyway?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/5586359 Text, please! http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode. [edit] your question, copy/paste from the terminal and properly [format](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) it as code. Images are not helpful, they're hard to read and hard to search. Badly formatted code is hard to read. Images are only good to show something non-textual (like colors, fonts, screen positions, etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get last 20 latest tags

```bash
git describe (git rev-list --tags --max-count=20)
```

Comment: Thanks but it is returning duplicates how do not return duplicates?

Comment: Sorry for the inaccurate answer, try `git tag --merged $(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD) | sort -nr | head -n 20` for date descending order, `git tag --merged $(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD) | tail -n 20` for ascending order.

Comment: The new command would only show tags that is in the current branch, if you want to show all tags from all branches, use @Özgür Murat Sağdıçoğlu's solution.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to @user6346643's answer:

```
git rev-list --tags | xargs -n1 git describe | uniq | head -20
```

Comment: if you have already selected commits referenced by a tag, you can use `git tag --points-at` rather than `git describe` : `... | xargs -n1 git tag --points-at`